# Who is shutting down my executor?

Tags: java, tomcat, executorservice

I have a server that uses an execution service that is created at server start:

```
simpleExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads, new MyThreadFactory(threadFactoryName));
```

I then use the executor service instance to execute some task. But after a short while (30 minutes or so) I get this:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1768)
```

I've read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) that this can happen when the executor is shut down. I never shut it down, so how can this be happening? Any ideas of how to debug such a problem?

Comment: Dummy question but who knows -- are you sure the tasks you submit actually terminate?

Comment: Dummy or not, the issue is there and production is blocked so I need to get done with very little information.

Comment: Can you at least obtain a thread dump from the server (kill -3 if you use a Sun/Oracle JVM will send that to stderr, and therefore probably to some log file)?

Comment: Had not thought of a thread dump, good idea. I have limited log access, but I can make them configure catalina logs if this can dump executor service traces?

Comment: A thread dump will dump each and every thread, regardless of where they "come from". As to where the dump will go, it is always to stderr, so it depends on how your hosting provider has configured it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same page you linked to:

> New tasks submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable) will be
>   rejected when the Executor has been shut down, and also when the
>   Executor uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue
>   capacity, and is saturated.

So maybe the work queue's full and the thread count is maxed out?

Do you have any visibility into whats it doing? Via JMX? Attached profiler? Debug logging? Anything?

Comment: I don't have control over the server, it's some other company, I requested jmx access to monitor tomcat but I don't think they will give it to me. The Tomcat thread pool and queue size is set to default so large enough.

Comment: Can 'maxIdleTime' connector configuration shutdown the executor threads?

Comment: the threads, yes, but the entire executor service? i dont think so